# Is it possible to commit a transaction that is waiting to RollBack?

Tags: mysql, aurora

I'm using Aurora MySql 5.6.10a and a query that was loading a table with 700 million rows crashed and now it's rolling back. I turned autocommit off to try to speed the data load up, but now it's giving me a huge headache.

When i run `` SELECT * FROM `information_schema`.`innodb_trx` ORDER BY `trx_started`; `` it returns the following:

```
3175241 ROLLING BACK    0000-00-00 00:00:00         335482132
3098119 RUNNING         0000-00-00 00:00:00         441106325
```

Is it possible to revert this rollback and commit those changes? At least, can I commit the running query?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ROLLBACK` must finish in order to get the database back to a table state.

(Without knowing the details of the load, I cannot advise on `autocommit`.)

Comment: Hi, @Rick James! Thanks for the reply. I looked up for more information in other posts and found a fine solution to me. This was a test environment, so I could drop the table and started the bulk load again.